# Function that is 0 for all positive integers divisible by x and 1 otherwise

Tags: mathematics, functional-equation

I am working on dice probabilities and I need a function where every xth item of the set of positive integers > 0 (n) is 0 and 1 otherwise.*  x is also a positive integers.

So, can you, without the use of indicator functions, find an [elementary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) function that satisfies

$$f(n,x)=
\begin{cases} 0 &\text{if $n \bmod x = 0$},\\
1 &\text{if $n \bmod x > 0$}
\end{cases}$$

I am trying to model a die roll where if you roll a max on the dice, you roll again and add the new roll.  This is recursive, so long as you keep rolling the max amount on each roll.  x, i the dice type (d4, d6, etc) and n is the number you want to roll.  The probabilities are fairly simple *except* for the case there you roll max die.  Under this system it is impossible to get a total roll of 6 on a d6, because you immediately roll the dice and add the new number.

Similar, to this [question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/33625/function-that-is-1-for-all-positive-integers-but-0-at-0). But slightly more generalized.  But it is trying to introduce a periodic function, similar to what I need.

* *Obviously the inverse would work as well since 1- f(x) will flip the bit.*

Comment: Not for an elementary function, no.  I went down that route, and it does give a solution, the problem come when you try to do s summation.

Comment: Relevant links: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/51762/1072645, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1422895/1072645

Comment: Why would anyone downvote this?!  If someone doesn't understand a puzzle they haven't even left the locker room.

Comment: @rotta I didn't downvote, but I speculate that others may have felt this question has already been asked before (see above links).

Comment: As such, @BeKind, thank you for commenting with relevant comparisons.  It serves better than any vote.

Comment: I didn't downvote either, but is this more a puzzle or a math problem?

Comment: @JLee : The math and puzzle exchanges seem to have their own specific etiquette like : on math one is rather supposed to ask help for something one does not know (and one is down-voted for something one knows) whereas on puzzle one can challenge others to search for something one does know. But then ... puzzles can be math. This creates a black hole of questions that  are popular to neither math nor puzzle (as I experienced myself). Maybe the question where this question belongs to belongs to a meta meta exchange. I think it is just fine here :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $\omega=\exp(2\pi i/x)$ be the primitive $x$th root of unity.  Note that $$\frac{1+\omega^n+\omega^{2n}+\dots+\omega^{(x-1)n}}{x}=\begin{cases}1&\text{if $x \mid n$}\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
So your desired function is
$$1-\frac{1+\omega^n+\omega^{2n}+\dots+\omega^{(x-1)n}}{x}$$
For example, $x=2$ yields
$$1-\frac{1+\omega^n}{2}=1-\frac{1+(-1)^n}{2}=\frac{1-(-1)^n}{2}$$